# Jboss remote project deployment

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, jboss, intellij-idea

Cant catch, how to do it. Have linux vps, wildfly(jboss) and cant deploy my war via intellij idea.
Try to do it with IDEA tool, add remote jboss server, but no way to deploy artifact.
Try to deploy war from maven via wildfly(jboss) admin panel, but maven cant run all tests, not sure why, artifact compile, build and work fine on local server.
Any good way to do it manualy or via IDEA?

Answer (score 0):

My practice (manually):

Within IntelliJ, from maven, clean and install the project, then copy the WAR files from project directory to the jboss deployment folder (some location like this: jboss-as-7.x.x.Final\standalone\deployments). See the terminal for output, it will show a clear message that "projectX" has been deployed. Also, in the deployment folder you will see the deployed file named as "projectX.deployed".